# Pivot_wider with two value columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following **dataset: filtered_input**. It has the columns: year_group, exporter, FVA_origin, FYavgShares. year_group has four different values. The set is pre-sorted by descending value of FYavgShares.

**I want to spread the columns** so that FVA_origin and FYavgShares are extended by a corresponding value of year group, e.g.
FVA_origin_1999-2002 and FYavgShares_1999-2002 or FVA_origin_2007-2010 and FYavgShares_2007-2010 with their corresponding values.

Here is a **sample** from my code:

```
<fctr>
exporter
<chr>
FVA_origin
<chr>
FYavgShares
<dbl>
2015-2018   AGO EU27    20.2072539  
1999-2002   AGO EU27    11.4285714  
2003-2006   AGO EU27    9.5238095   
2015-2018   AGO PRT 9.2000000   
2011-2014   AGO EU27    9.1503268   
2007-2010   AGO EU27    8.0000000   
2015-2018   AGO BRA 6.1000000   
1999-2002   AGO PRT 5.7000000   
2015-2018   AGO ZAF 5.5000000   
1999-2002   AGO ZAF 4.4000000
2015-2018   AGO USA 4.0000000   
2003-2006   AGO ZAF 3.8000000   
2003-2006   AGO PRT 3.5000000   
1999-2002   AGO USA 3.4000000   
2011-2014   AGO PRT 3.1000000   
2007-2010   AGO ZAF 3.0000000   
2011-2014   AGO ZAF 3.0000000   
2015-2018   AGO ESP 3.0000000   
2007-2010   AGO PRT 2.9000000   
2015-2018   AGO CHN 2.4000000   
2003-2006   AGO USA 2.2000000   
2015-2018   AGO FRA 2.2000000   
1999-2002   AGO FRA 2.1000000   
2015-2018   AGO DEU 2.1000000   
1999-2002   AGO DEU 2.0000000   
2011-2014   AGO BRA 2.0000000   
1999-2002   AGO BRA 1.9000000   
2003-2006   AGO BRA 1.9000000   
2015-2018   AGO GBR 1.9000000   
2007-2010   AGO BRA 1.8000000
```

The **desired output** should look somehow like this. Sorted by descending value of FYavgShares in each year-group (This is already pre-sorted in the dataset).

| exporter | FVA_origin_1999-2002 | FYavgShares_1999-2002 | FVA_origin_2003-2006 | FYavgShares_2003-2006 | FVA_origin_2007-2010 | FYavgShares_2007-2010 | FVA_origin_2011-2014 | FYavgShares_2011-2014 | FVA_origin_2015-2018 | FYavgShares_2015-2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGO | EU27 | 11.42857 | EU27 | 9.523810 | EU27 | 8.0 | EU27 | 9.1503268 | EU27 | 20.207254 |
| AGO | PRT | 5.7 | ZAF | 3.80 | ZAF | 3.0 | ZAF | 9.1503268 | PRT | 9.200000 |

My current problem is that whichever option I try I get an error. The data contains duplicates for 'exporter'- 'year_group'combinations.
Some examples of **what I tried**:

```
# alternative 1
step1 <- filtered_input %>%
  mutate(across(c(FVA_origin, FYavgShares), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(FVA_origin, FYavgShares), names_to = "indicator", values_to = "value")

step2 <- input_gather%>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = c(indicator, year_group),
        values_from = value
    )
```

**Problem:** This option creaates individual rows with only one value for each exporter, year_group combinations, instead of listing all values in the same row.

```
# alternative 2
alternative <- filtered_input %>% 
  # select relevant columns
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(year_group), values_from = FYavgShares)
```

**Problem:**  This one only spreads the year_group with the values of FYavgShares. However, I want to do this with both columns (also with FVA_origin).

```
# alternative 3
alternative <- filtered_input %>% 
  # select relevant columns
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(year_group), values_from = FYavgShares)
```

**Problem:** This one creates entries with lists, instead of individual values, because of duplicates in exporter, year_group combinations.

Comment: Can you please include the desired output in the post so we can test and verify possible solutions. What exactly do you want to happen with the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting your data as a dput output would be helpful to allow others to bring the data into R simply. After pasting the data string you provided I eventually landed on this as a way to get it into a dataframe.

```
df <- string %>% 
 str_replace_all("[^\\S\\r\\n]+", " ") %>%
  readr::read_delim(
    file = .,
    delim = " ",
    col_names = FALSE,
    show_col_types = FALSE
  )

df <- df[,1:4]  
names(df) <- c("year_group", "exporter", "FVA_origin", "FYavgShares")
```

Anyways my complaints aside, I've gotten pretty close to having what you want.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(FVA_origin) %>%
  mutate(label = FVA_origin) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(label, exporter), names_from = year_group, names_sort = TRUE, values_from = FVA_origin:FYavgShares) %>% 
  select(-label)
```

I think the main useful elements was adding the label column as it got around the issue of columns not being unique.
I assume you were expecting some NA values for some of the regions.
The column order isn't interspersed as you were asking for. Unless someone else answers in the meantime I'll try and revisit this later.

Hope this is helpful!